# How to align react-bootstrap modal relative to the button clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap-modal  [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-examples), I want to show my modal relative to the button clicked, I have an option in my react-bootstrap-table so when I clik on that option I am showing my modal, but it is not aligning relatively.

1. I am using `contentClassName` to override `.modal-content`, I don't know but it is not working as expected

   ```
         <Modal
           show={props.show}
           onHide={props.handleClose}
           contentClassName="modal_l" // this is I am doing to override
           aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
           <div className="container_modal_options">
               <div className="heading">Heading</div>
               <div className="content">"content</div>
           </div>
       </Modal>
   ```

Here I am sharing minimal code,

```
    .modal_l {
      width: 100px !important; it is not taking styling
    }
```

I want to show modal at the right side, near by click

[This is my code sand box working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-tdd-cvuqq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You might want to checkout [Popover](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#popovers).

Answer (score 0):

You should change `contentClassName` to `dialogClassName`.

```
.modal_l {
  width: 100px !important;
  max-width: none !important;// set max-width, if needed. 
}
```

Comment: but this is not helping in showing modal  relevant to clicked text